# Exoplayer not sending RTSP request

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer2.x, media-source

I need to receive a local host RTSP stream and display it in my jetpack compose android application.

The RTSP stream is being hosted through docker via 'aler9/rtsp-simple-server' , and is tested and functionally up and running.

I have implemented exoplayer correctly but the prepare statement from my Exoplayer isn't really being executed properly. Since I don't receive the call in my docker command line for the ports

Code that is being executed:

```kotlin
// Fetching the Local Context
                        val mContext = LocalContext.current


                        // Create a player instance.
                        var player = ExoPlayer.Builder(mContext).build()

                        // Set the media item to be played.
                        val rtspUri = "rtsp://10.0.2.2:8554/test"

                        var mediaSource = RtspMediaSource.Factory().createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(rtspUri))
                        player.setMediaSource(mediaSource)


                        // Prepare the player.
                        player.prepare()

//                      player.playWhenReady = true

                        // Implementing ExoPlayer
                        AndroidView(factory = { context ->
                            PlayerView(context).apply {
                                player = player
                            }
                        })
```

I have also added the internet permission to the AndroidManifest.xml

```kotlin
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Tried to receive RTSP stream through Exoplayer but the call is never made